WKWebView not loading in iOS 17.5 beta | Xcode 15.4 beta
This code has functioned flawlessly for years, but after updating to Xcode 15.4 (Beta 1), the WebView is not rendering the content. I have updated to Xcode 15.4 because I'm having this issue on Xcode Cloud since Xcode 15 released. As a temporary measure, I've switched the URL to google.com for testing purposes.
This is the code that I'm using on my project to load a URL but nothing is loading on iOS 17.5 (simulator), and it does load on iOS 17.4 (simulator and real device).
import WebKit
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            WebView(urlString: "https://google.com")
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Web View")
    }
}

#Preview {
    LoginView()
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

let urlString: String

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
    return webView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}
}

iPhone 15 Pro Max iOS 17.5 (Simulator)

iPhone 15 Pro Max iOS 17.4 (Simulator)

Xcode Cloud UITests using iPhone 15 Pro Max iOS 17.4 (Simulator)
I also noticed that Xcode Cloud has been having problems rendering the WebView as you can see in the image below:


Looks like an iOS Simulator bug, you'll likely need to wait until Apple fixes the bug.

Not just the simulator, but the released code for 17.4.1 of iOS.  The simulator code for 17.4 doesn't have it, but the simulator code for 17.5 beta 2 does. In the simulator, you get the terse error message: Error launching process, description 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)', reason ''

I noticed that log as well. I hope Apple has a fix for that because I've seen this issue on Xcode Cloud since Xcode 15 was released and I don't have a clue why it starts happening on Xcode Cloud first.

Suddenly, the functionality started working again for me without a change in code. No more error -10814 and correct operation.  Hope yours turns out the same!

@OwenHartnett I'm still having the same issue. Did you have used the iOS 17.5?
